# JavaScript runs in Firefox, but not IE or Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, jquery-events

I have the following JavaScript in my site :

```
 $(function() {
    var $cells = $("td");

    $("#search").keyup(function() {
        var val = $.trim(this.value).toUpperCase();
        if (val === "")
            $cells.parent().show();
        else {
            $cells.parent().hide();
            $cells.filter(function() {
                return -1 != $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val);
            }).parent().show();
        }
    });
});​
```

[Link to it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/k5hkR/1/)

This example works in all browsers, so I assume the problem is with my HTML somewhere. Here is the relevant part:

```
  <div id="searchContainer">
                <input id="search" type="text">
            </div>
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Full name</th> 
                    <th>Tick to select</th>
               </tr>
           @foreach (var user in result) {
            <tr><td>@user.Username</td> <td>@user.FirstName @user.SecondName</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="userId" value="@user.UserId" /></td></tr>
                }
```

The error I am thinking must be here since the code works perfectly in Firefox but does not run at all in Chrome or IE.

Comment: What part of this doesn't work? Typing in the box filters the list in chrome 17.

Comment: Typing in the box in Chrome does not filter with my HTML, using the same JavaScript function.

Comment: Have a look in the Chrome developer tools window. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @Nik Just had a look using Firebug for Chrome and it's not picking up any bugs as far as I can see. But nothing is also happening on keystroke!

Comment: Works in IE8 too. Type in the text box and it filters out..

Comment: Not with my HTML it doesn't! The jsfiddle works fine; with my HTML; Chrome and IE don't work.

Comment: is your templating engine javascript or server side based?  If its js and you fire your listener before the html is rendered, it won't pick up all the TD columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because you are missing the closing / on your input search box...

```
<input id="search" type="text">
```

should be

```
<input id="search" type="text" />
```

If not, try posting the generated source, to ensure what the client is actually seing rather than what asp.net is seeing (I'm assuming you are using Asp.net mvc with razor?).